# Apps Duplicate When Installed

Tags: android, installation, duplicates

I recently made an app. When its installed it then instead of being one app there's four. I have no clue what causes this and am completely baffled. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When its installed it then instead of being one app there's four.

Most likely, there is only one app. There may be four launcher icons, though. My guess is that you elected to copy an `<activity>` element four times and wound up with four that have an `<intent-filter>` child that declares that activity to be something that should appear in the launcher. Only the activity that should appear in the launcher should have:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```